# Splitting Class into its Attributes in Lambda Expression in Java

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

Let's say you have a custom class:

```
public class T {
    int a;
    int b;
}
```

Is there a way you can split up the class in a lambda expression in the following way:

```
(Stream of T instances).forEach((a, b) -> {});
```

Comment: `stream.forEach(t -> {... t.a ... t.b ...});`?

Comment: No, you cannot use a BiConsumer this way natively.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java doesn't have the concept of tuples, so no! But there can be a workaround by converting the stream to a `Map` (***which has a lot of limitations and consequences***):

```
(Stream of T instances)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(t -> t.a, t -> t.b))
    .forEach((a, b) -> {});
```

Comment: why convert to a `Map` even? and what limitations and consequences are related to OP's problem?

Comment: @Naman I certainly don't need to justify the limitations of converting stream to a map. You are free to post an answer that has `BiConsumer` rather than criticizing my post(as always).